# ConstraintLayout with chain makes the view jump

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

Update: Adding screenshot of desired result

I've this simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        style="@style/LoginBlueButtonsV2"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" textview"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/text1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to have `text2` at the top,
`text1` and `text3` chained horizontally and constrained to the bottom
and have `button`  chained vertically to `text1`.

The result is that everything is jumping to the top

[image]

This is the desired result:

[image]

I can't figure why.

I've spent hours on hours trying to find a solution and understand what's wrong here...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a design/screenshot of the desired layout?

Comment: Can you sketch your needs and upload it with label on the view to make it more clear .

Comment: Hey @KishanMaurya  I've added screenshot of desired result

Comment: Hey @KaruneshPalekar I've added screenshot of desired result

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from text1.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button"
```

Comment: the question is why? I know that removing it will solve the problem, but i wonder why it happens

Comment: As per your layout, you have to fix Text1 at the bottom and the material button on top of that. 

For text1, you are writing that it's top to bottom of button, 
and for the button, its bottom to the top of text1. making it circular-dependent.

Comment: but isn't what chain is?

Comment: For that, you also need to add vertical biasing and chain style between text1 and button else it will not form a chain and behave misaligned.